# Percentage of non-numeric answers in PivotTable?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, percentage, worksheet-function, countif

I received an Excel spreadsheet of survey answers and I'm trying to figure out how to created a PivotTable that will give me the percentage of total respondents who responded with each (non-numeric) answer. For example, this is one of the columns in the table I was given:

```
How many assets are in your organization?
------------------------------------------
Less than $1 million
$1 million - $5 million
$1 million - $5 million
Less than $1 million
Less than $1 million
Less than $1 million
$1 million - $5 million
Less than $1 million
Less than $1 million
Less than $1 million
$1 million - $5 million
Less than $1 million
$1 million - $5 million
Less than $1 million
Less than $1 million
$1 million - $5 million
Less than $1 million
$1 million - $5 million
Less than $1 million
$1 million - $5 million
Less than $1 million
Less than $1 million
Less than $1 million
$200 million - $500 million
```

I need to generate results i.e.:

Less than $1 million:  40%
$200 million - $500 million: 20%
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your results are in Column A for example, then something like:

`="Less than $1 million: "&(COUNTIF(A:A,"Less than $1 million")/COUNTA(A:A))*100&"%"`

should do you.

If you have a header in Row 1 then change `COUNTA(A:A)` to `COUNTA(A:A)-1`

based on your example above, this formula would return "Less than $1 million: 62.5%"

Answer (score 0):

SO'S answer is exactly what you need but if there are lots of different values in your data column A:A I'd go one step further and make a copy of the column, paste it in an adjacent column (assuming column B here but could be anywhere you want to summarise), use excel's remove duplicates feature to leave a list of unique values and then change the formula to

=(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)/COUNTA(A:A))*100&"%"

I'd put this in C1 and then paste it down against all the unique values in column B.

Answer (score 0):

With a PT as mentioned:

[image: S27406891 example]

and one of the "Count of"s  with Show Values As `% of Grand Total`.